# Handle command line arguments with different radices in Perl

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, hex

When used as literals in a Perl program, numbers are handled in the same way as in C:  "0x" prefix means hexadecimal, "0" prefix means octal, and no prefix means decimal:

```
$ perl -E 'print 0x23 . "\n"'
35
$ perl -E 'print 023 . "\n"'
19
$ perl -E 'print 23 . "\n"'
23
```

I would like to pass command line arguments to Perl using the same notation.  e.g. If I pass 23, I want to convert the string argument to a decimal value (23).  If I pass 0x23, I want to convert to a hexadecimal value (35), and 023 would be converted to octal (19).  Is there a built-in way to handle this?  I am aware of hex() and oct(), but they interpret numbers with no prefix to be hex/oct respectively (not decimal).  Following this convention, it seems that I want a dec() function, but I don't think that exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/419-convert-binary-octal-and-hexidecimal-numbers-in-perl/:

```
print "Gimme an integer in decimal, binary, octal, or hex: ";
$num = <STDIN>;
chomp $num;
exit unless defined $num;
$num = oct($num) if $num =~ /^0/; # catches 077 0b10 0x20
printf "%d %#x %#o %#bn", ($num) x 4;
```

Comment: Didn't know `oct()` could convert hex and binary as well; wouldn't be able to tell from the name

Comment: Neither did I - good trick to know. Always something new to learn in `perlfunc`. +1.

Comment: The oct() one-liner is perfect.  Thanks!